# How to deal with conflict of brew formulas?

Tags: homebrew

For example, I want to be able to access errno from both moreutils and pwntools. Is there a way to just print out the installed directory of a package (in this case `/usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.64`) so that I can directory call the command with a full path (in this case `/usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.64/bin/errno`)?

```
$ brew info moreutils
moreutils: stable 0.65 (bottled), HEAD
Collection of tools that nobody wrote when UNIX was young
https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/
Conflicts with:
  parallel (because both install a `parallel` executable)
  pwntools (because both install an `errno` executable)
  sponge (because both install a `sponge` executable)
  task-spooler (because both install a `ts` executable)
/usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.64 (68 files, 623.8KB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-09-04 at 23:44:26
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/moreutils.rb
License: GPL-2.0-or-later and (GPL-2.0-only or Artistic-2.0)
==> Dependencies
Build: docbook-xsl ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 2,161 (30 days), 9,268 (90 days), 28,848 (365 days)
install-on-request: 2,158 (30 days), 9,224 (90 days), 28,139 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Comment: `brew ls moreutils` maybe?

Comment: Too slow. Is there a quick way to get the path `/usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.64` just by specifying `moreutils`?